# how can i send and receive data from server with Volley for login form

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to send username and password to server,and I want to receive another user's info from server with Volley.Can you help me?

I want send stringrequest and receive jsonarrayrequest but I dont now how do it.

this is my php code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Getting values 
    $username = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];     
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "-------" , "--------");//change server name  //pass username according your settings

    mysql_select_db("--------");// also chang the Mysql database name
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 
    $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE email='$username' AND password='$password'");

    if (!$sql1) {

    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();

    exit;

    }

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))

    $output[]=$row;


    //print(json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));// this will print the output in json
    echo preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode($output));

    mysql_close();

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: I send username and password to a php file with POST method,if this user was valid, returned another field of this user on json code to me.how can I get this jsonarray code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an JSONObject contains username and password and receive an JSONObject contains the info of the user or error message.Use Volley,like this:

```
JSONObject loginJSon = new JSONObject();
//then put your parameter to this jsonobejct,maybe username and password
//loginJson.put("username",<username>)
this.requestQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(<URL_LOGIN>,//your login url
            loginJson, new Listener<JSONObject>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONObject easyJsonObject) {
                    //here can get response from your server,just take the value as its key
                        String uid = easyJsonObject.getString("uid"));

                }
            }, this));
```

Comment: But I receive jsonarray

Comment: there is error in this line.
String uid = easyJsonObject.getString("uid"));
i can't use string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (!jsonArray.isNull(0)){
                                String name=jsonObj.getString("name");

                            }else {
                                //If the server response is not success
                                //Displaying an error message on toast

                            };

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                       //error
                    }
```